# PHP - getting the content of php page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a controller inside which a server is connected to the network when searching with this URL http://192.168.1.3/query.php A window appears with information on input and output states as follows (& LOCATION = & DI = 0,1,1,1,1,1,1, 1,1,1 & DO = 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 & DATE = 2000,01,01 & TIME = 02,41,17).
I want to take this content in some way with either javascript or php.

Notice : this is the html code of the page :

```
<html><head></head><body>
  & LOCATION = & DI = 0,1,1,1,1,1,1, 1,1,1 & DO = 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 & DATE = 2000,01,01 & TIME = 02,41,17</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can consume this html data using JavaScript. If you want to pass it off to another page you can use PHP.

In order to get the content of `query.php` you need to have access to it's `DOM`. You can get access to its `DOM` either directly or if you're unable to write code on this page you can just open `query.php` in an `<iframe>` and get access to the `DOM` that way.

Refer to https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_frame_contentdocument.asp for more information on that.

Once you have access to the `DOM` you can just run a line of JavaScript similar to `const myContent = document.body.innerHTML` and you'll access the content you're looking for.

Then you can transfer that data into an `<input id='myInput' name='myInput'>` by setting it's value like `document.getElementById('myInput').value = myContent` then you can submit this data from a form and access it with PHP.

Comment: Thank you for your response, the solution is helpful with every url except my url. I think because the url is php file inside the server of  controller, So I can't take the text for the security.

Comment: Does the window that pops up with the content not have a url?

Comment: She has a url and that is it http://192.168.1.3/query.php

Comment: Why can't you open that url in an `<iframe>` (refer to this https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_iframe_contentdocument2) And then use JavaScript to extract the information you need.

Comment: Forgive me, I did not explain well. The window opens and the text appears, but it cannot be taken with javascript. As for https://www.w3schools.com/ for example the program works efficiently.

Comment: Just to be certain the window opens to a specific url http://192.168.1.3/query.php. Why can’t you open it in an invisible `<iframe style=‘display: hidden’>`

Comment: If it opens in a `<iframe>` window you can for sure execute JavaScript inside it. Otherwise there’s no other obvious solution that I can think of.

Comment: The same problem I get when I use a php library, I don't know why?                                 I am really greatful for your help.